# YouTube video Downloader python

Tags: python, download-manager, pafy

I made a youtube video download Manager. It download a video but i am facing one issue when i download same video, it doesn't download it again. how can i download it again with same title like pic.png and send pic1.png. How can i do that?

```
def Download(self):
    video_url = self.lineEdit.text()
    save_location = self.lineEdit_2.text()
    if video_url == '' or save_location == '':
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Data Error", "Provide a Valid Video URL or save Location")

    else:
        video = pafy.new(video_url)
        video_stream = video.streams
        video_quality = self.comboBox.currentIndex()

        download = video_stream[video_quality].download(filepath=save_location, callback=self.Handel_Progress, )
```

Comment: which lib you are using? `pafy.new(video_url)`

Comment: what error message are you getting exactly?

Comment: no error is given and no response it

Comment: i am using pafy library

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this one is interesting.

The real problem begins here.

```
    download = video_stream[video_quality].download(filepath=save_location, callback=self.Handel_Progress, )
```

Here, you are calling `download` function of `video_stream` object which takes `filepath` as an argument for file location but does not take the filename, because, obviously, the file would be saved with the actual name.

**Root Cause of your problem:**

> If you look into the definition of `download` function, you would find that if a file exists with the same name, it would not download the file at all.

**Now comes the part, how do you make sure it downloads, no matter what:**

There are two things you need to do:

1. Check if a file with same name exists or not, and if does, then add `1` in the end of the file name just before the extension. So if `abc.mp4` exists, then save `abc1.mp4`. 
   [I will tell you how to handle the scenario when `abc.mp4`, `abc1.mp4` and so on exists, but for now, let's get back to the problem.]
2. How to pass the file name (`abc1.mp4`) to the download method?

Following piece of code would handle both. 
I have added comments for your understanding.

```
import os
import re

import pafy
from pafy.util import xenc


# this function is used by pafy to generate file name while saving,
# so im using the same function to get the file name which I will use to check
# if file exists or not
# DO NOT CHANGE IT
def generate_filename(title, extension):
    max_length = 251

    """ Generate filename. """
    ok = re.compile(r'[^/]')

    if os.name == "nt":
        ok = re.compile(r'[^\\/:*?"<>|]')

    filename = "".join(x if ok.match(x) else "_" for x in title)

    if max_length:
        max_length = max_length + 1 + len(extension)
        if len(filename) > max_length:
            filename = filename[:max_length - 3] + '...'

    filename += "." + extension
    return xenc(filename)


def get_file_name_for_saving(save_location, full_name):
    file_path_with_name = os.path.join(save_location, full_name)

    # file exists, add 1 in the end, otherwise return filename as it is
    if os.path.exists(file_path_with_name):
        split = file_path_with_name.split(".")
        file_path_with_name = ".".join(split[:-1]) + "1." + split[-1]

    return file_path_with_name


def Download(self):
    video_url = self.lineEdit.text()
    save_location = self.lineEdit_2.text()
    if video_url == '' or save_location == '':
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Data Error", "Provide a Valid Video URL or save Location")

    else:
        # video file
        video = pafy.new(video_url)

        # available video streams
        video_stream = video.streams
        video_quality = self.comboBox.currentIndex()

        # video title/name
        video_name = video.title

        # take out the extension of the file from video stream
        extension = video_stream[video_quality].extension

        # fullname with extension
        full_name = generate_filename(video_name, extension)

        final_path_with_file_name = get_file_name_for_saving(save_location, full_name)

        download = video_stream[video_quality].download(filepath=final_path_with_file_name,
                                                        callback=self.Handel_Progress, )
```

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: yes i am facing a problem it does not run the code it stop

Comment: can you share you code in a zip? and what are your input?

Comment: where i share you?